# Filtering data using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter

I'm new to angular and am trying to filter data. I've created a webpage displaying a list of hotels, but would like to filter them by their star rating. I'm usnure on how to even attempt this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

hotels.componenent.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'hotels',
  templateUrl: './hotels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hotels.component.css']
})
export class HotelsComponent {

    hotel_list: any;
    page: number = 1;

    constructor(public webService: WebService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (sessionStorage['page']) {
          this.page = Number(sessionStorage['page'])
        }
        this.hotel_list = this.webService.getHotels(this.page);
    }
```

Web services.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class WebService {

    private hotelID: any;


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getHotels(page: number) { 
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/hotels?pn=' + page);

    }
```

hotels.components.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div *ngFor = "let hotel of hotel_list | async">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" 
                     style ="cursor : pointer"
                     [routerLink]="['/hotels', hotel._id]">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ hotel.hotel }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This hotel is based in
                        {{ hotel.city }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        {{ hotel.rating }}
                        stars
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are these filter criteria you expected to be applied need to happen at the UI level or API level? Is the API support querying the hotels by their rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to filter the hostels on the client side after fetching the hotels. That is, only the hotels returned for page = 1.

in hotels.componenent.ts :

```
filtered_hotels_list: any = []; //empty array
//......
    ngOnInit() {
        if (sessionStorage['page']) {
          this.page = Number(sessionStorage['page'])
        }
        this.webService.getHotels(this.page).subscribe(data => { 
                this.hotel_list = data
                this.filter();
        });
        
}
filter(rating:number = -1) { // rating = -1 shows all
     if(rating > -1) {
         this.filtered_hotels_list = this.hotel_list.filter((o:any) => o.rating == rating)
     } else this.filtered_hotels_list = this.hotel_list
 
}
```

in hotels.components.html:

```
<div *ngFor = "let hotel of filtered_hotel_list">
```

And implement your UI to add a filter button, which calls the filter(5) function.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I'm getting an error for (o => o.rating == rating), saying 'parameter o implicitly has any type'. any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: if you have a `Hotel` class, use `o: Hotel`. Otherwise, `o: any` should do it.

Comment: this.filtered_hotels_list = this.hotel_list.filter((o: any) => o.rating == rating)

Comment: How would I implement this into my UI? This is what I have so far:
`<div class="dropdown">
    <div *ngFor = "let hotel of filtered_hotels_list"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5 Star</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4 Star</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3 Star</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2 Star</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Star</a>
    </div>
  </div>
`